# Unable to read all messages sent from client

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I want to read all messages that are sent from the client. 
I am implementing a tcp server and it receives data. Each message is appended by the size of the message as a header. So Now I can read the header and find the size from that and allocate that much memory for the message to be read later. However, with my very little exposure to C++ this is what I came up with.

How to read all messages  ?

```
 void *dothistask(void *socket_desc)
 {
   int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
   free(socket_desc);
   int read_size;
   unsigned int x = 4;
   char *header = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
   char *message;
   int index = 0;
   long p;

   int status;
   while(true) {
     status = ReadXBytes(sock, 4, header);
     if(status == -1)
     {
        break;
     }
     message = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
     status = ReadXBytes(sock, 10, message);
     if(status == -1)
     {
        break;
     }
     cout<<"The header is "<<header<<endl;
     cout<<"The message is "<<message<<endl;
   }

  return 0;

 }

 int ReadXBytes(int socket, unsigned int x, void* buff)
 {
   char *buffer = (char*)buff;
   int bytesRead = 0;
   int result;
   while (bytesRead < x)
   {
     result = recv(socket, buffer + bytesRead, x - bytesRead, 0);
     if(result == 0)
     {
        cout<<"Client disconnected"<<endl;
        fflush(stdout);
        return -1;
     }
     else if( result == -1)
     {
        perror("recv failed");
        return -1;
     }
     bytesRead += result;
   }
   return 0;
 }
```

Read that it is ideal to read the header first and then read the message. I am able to do this once but I want to do this over a repeated period of time, basically forever, till the client disconnects.

Thank you! for the help!

Comment: Beside the memory leak, what is the problem with the code you show? Doesn't it do what you want? Doesn't it build? Does it give you unexpected results? Please elaborate on the problems you have.

Comment: Assuming that all headers are 4 bytes and assuming that the 4 byte value comes up to be 10, I did that way. It does build! It only reads a part of the message. For eg, If I send "I am a newbie in c++" to server, it prints `The header is I am
The message is  a newbie ` leaving the last part `in c++`

Comment: Well if you send more data than the header indicates then your sender is broken. Also, what is the format of the header? Is it a string? A binary 4-byte integer? Will the data you receive be zero-terminated like a C-style string? If you just get the proper length from the header and use it, and fix the memory leak, then your code seems to be fine.

Comment: How you do this depends entirely on the format of the data you send. Your "header" appears to be a 32bit value, but you're not treating it as such beyond reading four octets, then effectively discarding it along with the memory you allocated to read it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it is a 4 byte integer. It will not be a c-string. I should add '\0'. but not sure why the sender is broken if it sends more data than it indicates. Can it not be the case of the remaining data a part of the new message. Here, each message, I assume, is combination of header and payload. I am simulating it to be a unlimited stream and so expect it to read the remaining part as well

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, can you also comment on memory leak. Also not sure if we can change the recv() to read()

Comment: @root memory leak = not freeing what you allocated (and this is C++, you shouldn't be using `malloc` in the first place unless you *really* know what you're doing and have a *very* good reason to do so). Btw, is your 32bit header in network-order or host-order ? If you don't know what that means, it may be worth researching.

Comment: mine is network order but I can do a ntohl. Thanks!

Comment: Also, does it differ if the 4 byte header is a string or a integer? Will there be a change in the way I read from the socket change should the header be an integer. ? thanks

Comment: @root if your sender prepares that value to be network order before sending, then yes, you should unprep it back to host-order once received. Utterly untested code, but [something like **this**](http://pastebin.com/g8qx5kpY).

Comment: Should I be changing the way I read if the header is an integer ? I think we can only read from the socket in the form of a charecter buffer and then should change it to a number using some of the library functions.

Comment: Btw, @WhozCraig thank you so much.@JoachimPileborg thanks a lot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110297/discussion-between-root-and-whozcraig).

Answer (score 1):

To read the message, you have

```
ReadXBytes(sock, 10, message);
```

but it should be something like

```
ReadXBytes(sock, *((int*)header), message);
```

depending on the content of header. As you have a hard-coded `10` in there, you will only ever read 10 bytes. You will also have to adjust the `malloc` accordingly to not only allocate 10 bytes.